# Php small code - Need a little help in correcting him

Tags: php

I need your help to advise me in correcting the php code to work properly. Thank you in advance!

If i had 10 products, the random function is no longer working, shows only 10 static results (no random).
The random function is working perfectly only if i put 9 products.
My request is to show all products (10) in random mode.

**My PHP Code**

```
 $files = array(
 "products/page1.php",
 "products/page2.php",
 "products/page3.php",
 "products/page4.php",
 "products/page5.php", 
 "products/page6.php", 
 "products/page7.php",
 "products/page8.php", 
 "products/page9.php", 
 "products/page10.php"
 );
 foreach (array_rand($files, 10) as $file) {
 include($files[$file]);
 }
?>
```

Comment: You want to [shuffle](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php) the array?!!

Comment: yes, to show all entries in random mode.

Comment: Ok then, problem solved ;)

Comment: Thank you for info! I just add shuffle($files); and everything works perfect.

Answer (score 0):

**Version 1 - My initial code**

```
$files = array(
 "products/page1.php",
 "products/page2.php",
 "products/page3.php",
 "products/page4.php",
 "products/page5.php", 
 "products/page6.php", 
 "products/page7.php",
 "products/page8.php", 
 "products/page9.php", 
 "products/page10.php"
 );
 shuffle($files);
 foreach (array_rand($files, 10) as $file) {
 include($files[$file]);
 }
?>
```

**Version 2 |  Thanks to Marcin Orlowski**

```
<?php
 $files = [
 "products/page1.php",
 "products/page2.php",
 "products/page3.php",
 "products/page4.php",
 "products/page5.php", 
 "products/page6.php", 
 "products/page7.php",
 "products/page8.php", 
 "products/page9.php", 
 "products/page10.php"
 ];
 shuffle($files);
 foreach (array_rand($files, 10) as $file) {
 require($files[$file]);
 }
?>
```

**Version 3 |  Thanks to  brombeer**

```
<?php
 $files = [
 "products/page1.php",
 "products/page2.php",
 "products/page3.php",
 "products/page4.php",
 "products/page5.php", 
 "products/page6.php", 
 "products/page7.php",
 "products/page8.php", 
 "products/page9.php", 
 "products/page10.php"
 ];
 shuffle($files);
foreach ($files as $key => $file) { require($file); }
?>
```

Comment: Consider using `require` instead of `include`. Also I'd drop `array()` in favor of short syntax `[]`

Comment: You can probably also drop `array_rand($files, 10)` and directly use the shuffled array `$files`

Comment: Brombeer, Thanks for the information, unfortunately I don't know how to assemble the code with the changes you suggested.

Comment: `foreach ($files as $key => $file) { require($file); }`